# How to set/change "parent user" field to show the combined flair in the chat user page?

Tags: support, bug, chat

Not sure if I can ask chat related question here. So, I clicked my username on a AE chat discussion site and a user information popup showing links to my profile,

> "user profile"  //which linked to
>   http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/149736/lucky
>
> "user profile on android.stackexchange.com"

I clicked on user profile and it opened [my chat user page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/149736/lucky). In the General tab page in my profile the link "parent user" was displayed with all the reputations greater than 200 was combined(2.6k) and displayed next to it. But once I changed it to stackoverflow.com and android enthusiasts, I can't set the "parent user" to display my combined reputations.

When I click the "change" and in the search box I typed "S" and "The Stack exchange Network" option appeared but the suggestions hides after selecting the option and doesn't have any effect in the profile page either. So How can I get it back to show the combined profile reps or What keywork I need to type in the search box for that?

**Update:**
Just recently after posting the question, I noticed that the reputation was shown from the AE site and the badges were shown from the combined profile flair.

[image: Screenshot]

Here in the screeshot the "462" is the reputation from the AE site and while  the badges(3gold, 24silver and 56bronze) are from the combined sites badges flair. So is combined flair not updating properly? or this is how it works.

Comment: I think you might need to wait a while after the change for the rep total to update.

Comment: @MatthewRead No, actually the rep total is displayed correctly for per site reputations..I'm taking here about the combined flair updating..my combined flair reputation is 2.6k..The first time I accessed this chat user page it was showing 2.6k. But when i changed it to Android Enthusiasts, 462 was displayed. what should I do to display the 2.6k reps back?

Comment: I think you need to wait for it to be recalculated, I believe this is part of a scheduled job rather than done instantly.  I could be wrong.

Comment: I just checked your chat user profile and it's displaying back 2.6k rep already, so I guess the issue is moot already? The only reason I can think why this happened is [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: Yeah It is display after changing the option set back to stack exchange network..sometimes the change works immediately and sometimes not it takes some time and sometimes the data is wrong..I selected travel site and it showed my combined reps under it..sometimes my profile picture is not updated properly after selecting a particular site..The next site I select after selecting the option "The stack exchange network" it is displaying the combined reputation etc..Its very confusing to me..its like different data(profile pic, reputation, site logo, badges) all mixed up together